# Can I transfer control to another handler in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a main route handler in Hapi.js that I need to send control to another handler based on the parameters sent.

For instance, if I POST a message with a type of 'twilio' I want to forward the request to a route handler contained in my twilio routes file. How do I forward the handler to another handler?

Comment: Take a look at http://hapijs.com/api#replycontinuedata

Comment: @Whisher would reply.redirect() not be applicable here?

Comment: @Whisher I think redirect returns a response to the client telling it to redirect to another location, which is not the behavior I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is contained here: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2515 by danielb2. You simply return the call to the handler you want to process the request and pass it the response and reply objects.

```
var twilioRoutes = require('./app/routes/twilio.js')(Hapi);
var emailRoutes = require('./app/routes/email.js')(Hapi);

server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/',
  handler: function(request, reply){
    if (request.payload.type == 'sms'){
      return twilioRoutes.sendSms(request, reply);
    } else if (request.payload.type == 'email'){
      return emailRoutes.sendEmail(request, reply);
    }
    // else
    return reply('Invalid Message Type');
  }
});
```